# In SQL Server how to shift rows for two columns

Tags: sql-server

This is the original table

```
Name    Marks_Original
Anil    10
Ravi    20
Pooja   30
Sheela  40
Rohit   50
Vijay   60
```

I want the output using 2 calculated columns as below where my 1st column record is static but my 2nd column records are shifting up and down respective to 1st column

```
Name    Marks_1  Marks_2
Anil    0        20
Ravi    10       30
Pooja   20       40
Sheela  30       50
Rohit   40       60
Vijay   50       0
```

Comment: Are we to assume "ORDER BY Marks_Original"?

Comment: You need to provide a large sample data set and expected output, and clarify your question. With what is given, any assumptions made on your data will likely lead to an answer that gives an output that you have listed, but will not solve your problem as you will likely state after a solution is given.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

Try the window functions (assuming the sequence is Marks_Original)

```
Select *
      ,Marks_1 = Lag(Marks_Original,1,0) over (Order By Marks_Original)
      ,Marks_2 = lead(Marks_Original,1,0) over (Order By Marks_Original)
 From  YourTable
 Order By Marks_Original
```

Returns

```
Name    Marks_Original  Marks_1 Marks_2
Anil    10              0       20
Ravi    20              10      30
Pooja   30              20      40
Sheela  40              30      50
Rohit   50              40      60
Vijay   60              50      0
```